# How can I get button-clicks from an Android dialog fragment back to the fragment (not an activity) which shows the dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

When the user commits a certain error in a certain fragment, a dialog is shown from a dialog fragment.  This works great!  However, I cannot figure out how to get the info on which button (positive or negative) is subsequently clicked on the dialog by the user back to the showing fragment.  (All the info I found addresses an "activity", not a "fragment".)